# Are BLS labor productivity measures in current dollars or constant dollars?

Tags: inflation, statistics, labor-cost

I am using BLS labor productivity measures to estimate the impact of automation in the US. Looking through the BLS handbook and online, I haven't been able to determine if the LPC measures are in current dollars or constant dollars. Do you happen to know?

For example, the BLS reports `Value of production` by industry in `$ millions`.  Is this a current-dollar or a constant-dollar measure?

BLS page on the topic & with access to data: http://www.bls.gov/lpc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which BLS numbers you look at

For example in Table 2 of http://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2013/article/industry-employment-and-output-projections-to-2022.htm it gives for manufacturing output:

```
Billions of chained 2005 dollars            Billions of dollars
      2002        2012                        2002        2012
    4,320.8     4,407.6                     3,848.3     5,604.8
```

and the first pair of numbers uses a constant dollar (more precisely a chain-weighted dollar) measure while the second pair uses a current dollar measure

For general productivity measures, the BLS says for example at http://www.bls.gov/opub/hom/pdf/homch12.pdf

> Time-series indexes of manufacturing labor productivity (output per hour) and unit labor costs are constructed from three  basic  aggregate  measures:  Total  real  output,  hours worked,  and  nominal  compensation.

So output per hour aims at a real measure of productivity, while unit labor costs divide a nominal figure by a real figure to give something which combines real productivity and nominal wages